# Compound expectations stopped working rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Recently my tests are started failing with following exception.

```
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `and' for #<Capybara::RSpecMatchers::Matchers::HaveText:0x00007f97687dbe30>
       Did you mean?  end
```

My tests looks like

```
it "starts german but allows to be changed to english" do
          within(".e-header") do
            # german locale
            expect(page).to have_content("Mein Anliegen").and not_have_content("My issue")
          end
end
```

Rspec 3.10 documentation for [compound expectations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/compound-expectations) still supporting it. I am not sure why suddenly my tests started failing.

Comment: Multiple expectations are already somewhat smelly - if you're going to do it I would at least be explicit and not use compound expectations.

Comment: Thats true I am also not in favour. but if you have legacy code. and it stop working you need to make it work right. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like `capybara` [will not include `compound` module](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers/base.rb#L11) if [rspec expectations is not be defined](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers/compound.rb#L3) (in other words, not require yet)

so try `require "rspec/expectations"` explicitly.

[the reason:](https://groups.google.com/g/ruby-capybara/c/PJHP2gjoK7A)

> it was due to the version range of RSpec we supported combined with the fact that a few people complained when we did because some people didn't want RSpec::Expectations.  Most people don't run into this issue because they're using Capybara with rspec-rails.

Comment: I tried requiring rspec/expectations in rails_helper, and it didn't work.  Somehow when capybara loads rspec/expectations still not loaded yet.

Comment: @AsadAli try `require "rspec/expectations"` in spec class

Comment: I tried already by requiring inside spec file as well but didn't work. I installed `gem "rspec-expectations"` then It worked.

Comment: wait, i thought `rspec` depend on `rspec-expectations` ? i read that if you install gem `rspec` that you also have `rspec-expectations`,you could check here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations, `just install the rspec gem and RubyGems will also install rspec-expectations for you (along with rspec-core and rspec-mocks)`

Comment: I am using rspec-rails gem. and this was also my intention. but loading order of capybara and rspec/expectations is not correct. I even tried changing order of require files in rails_helper it didn't changed anything, However adding `"rspec-expectations"` in gemfile fixed problem

Answer (score 0):

A very similar error happened when I ran my test suite with [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) enabled:

```
undefined method `and' for #<Capybara::RSpecMatchers::Matchers::HaveSelector
```

The answer in the comment by [Asad Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664558/compound-expectations-stopped-working-rspec#comment121355274_68665571) helped, just added:

`bundle add rspec-expectations --group test`

And the specs work with Spring.